# prove the limit of function

Tags: real-analysis

Can someone help me to solve this question? I appreciated it!
Let $f(x)$ be the function whose domain is all of $\mathbb{R}$ given by the rule
$$\begin{cases}
f(x) = 42 & \text{if } x \in \mathbb{Z}\\
f(x) = 0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Prove that for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$: $\lim_\limits{x \to a}f(x) = 0$.

Comment: yes,I know that I need to use definition (with ε and δ) but I do not know how to state it,can you show me?thanks

Comment: To state what? The definition? This should be in your lecture notes or textbook.

Comment: I mean the format of it

Comment: you have to prove that the limit of $f(x)$ is zero for $x$ approaching zero? (sorry, I do not completely understand your last line)

Comment: For $x\to a$. To do that: fix any $a\in\mathbb{R}$, then fix any $\varepsilon >0$. Show that there exists $\delta>0$ such that, for any $x\neq a$ such that $\lvert x-a\rvert \leq \delta$, you have $\lvert f(x)-0\rvert \leq \varepsilon$.

Comment: (My earlier comment was misleading. $\delta$ is allowed to depend on $\varepsilon$ and $a$, and contrary to what I had said it *will* depend on $a$ -- although not on $\varepsilon$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1)$\ \ $If $\,a\,$ is an integer, simply let $\,\delta=\frac12\,$ and we have

$$0<|x-a|<\delta=\frac12$$

$$\Rightarrow\ \ x\notin\mathbb Z$$

$$\Rightarrow\ \ |f(x)-0|=0<\text{any positive}\ \varepsilon$$

$$\left.\right.$$

(2)$\ \ $If $\,a\,$ is not an integer, then let $\,0<\delta<\min(a-\lfloor a\rfloor,\,\lceil a\rceil-a)$

Thus, for all $\,\varepsilon>0$, we have

$$|x-a|\ <\ \delta$$

$$\Rightarrow\ \ -\delta+a\ <\ x\ <\ \delta+a$$

$$\Rightarrow\ \ \max(\lfloor a\rfloor-a,a-\lceil a\rceil)+a\ <\ x\ <\ \min(a-\lfloor a\rfloor,\,\lceil a\rceil-a)+a$$

$$\Rightarrow\ \ \lfloor a\rfloor-a+a\ <\ x\ <\ \lceil a\rceil-a+a$$

$$\Rightarrow\ \ \lfloor a\rfloor\ <\ x\ <\ \lceil a\rceil$$

$$\Rightarrow\ \ x\notin\mathbb Z$$

$$\Rightarrow\ \ |f(x)-0|=|0-0|=0<\varepsilon$$

Comment: Thanks!That's what I thought.And do you think I can set δ=(a- n)/2(n is the closest integer of a) when a is not an integer.

Comment: No worries :) and of course you can define $n$ to be the closest integer to $a$, which will be essentially the same as this argument.